# Preserving WebView Cache in Flutter After App Termination

Tags: flutter, dart, caching, flutter-dependencies

I am facing challenges with maintaining the cache of a WebView in Flutter when the app is terminated and restarted. In a typical web scenario, reopening a previously visited page loads faster due to cached content. In my Flutter WebView, even after terminating and reopening the app, the WebView content takes as long to load as it did initially.

I've used the [webview_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter) package  to load web content, but the cache doesn't seem to persist after app termination. Here's my code:

```
class WebProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  late WebViewController controller;
  bool _isWebViewLoading = true;
  final Auth0 auth0 = Auth0(AppConfig.DOMAIN, AppConfig.CLIENTID);

  bool get isWebViewLoading => _isWebViewLoading;

  void loadWebView({String? url}) {
    final dashboardUrl = Uri.parse(AppConfig.login).replace(queryParameters: {
      'access_token': PrefUtils.getString(ACCESS_TOKEN),
      'token_type': PrefUtils.getString(TOKEN_TYPE),
      'refresh_token': PrefUtils.getString(REFRESH_TOKEN),
      'expires_in': PrefUtils.getString(EXPIRES_AT),
      'id_token': PrefUtils.getString(ID_TOKEN),
      'scope': PrefUtils.getString(SCOPES)
    }).toString();

    controller = WebViewController()
      ..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted)
      ..setNavigationDelegate(NavigationDelegate(
        onPageStarted: (url) async {
          _isWebViewLoading = true;
          notifyListeners();
        },
        onPageFinished: (url) async {
          log("url on finish: $url");
          _isWebViewLoading = false;
          notifyListeners();
        },
        onNavigationRequest: (navigation) async {
          if (navigation.url.contains(AppConfig.LOGOUT_URL)) {
            if (PrefUtils.getBool(SOCIAL_LOGIN) == true) {
              try {
```

//logout code
} catch (e) {}
}

```
            PrefUtils.removeValue(ACCESS_TOKEN);
            PrefUtils.removeValue(USER_EMAIL);
            PrefUtils.setBool(SOCIAL_LOGIN, false);

            // redirect to login page
            Get.offAll(() => const LoginPage());
          }

          return NavigationDecision.prevent;
        },
      ))
      ..loadRequest(Uri.parse(dashboardUrl))
      ..setBackgroundColor(
          Colors.transparent); // Set background color if needed
  }
}
```

I also experimented with the [flutter_inappwebview](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview) package  and [flutter_webview_plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview) , enabling app cache, but the issue persists, with web pages taking a considerable time to load.
code with flutter_webview_plugin:

```
class WebProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  final FlutterWebviewPlugin flutterWebviewPlugin = FlutterWebviewPlugin();
  bool _isWebViewLoading = true;
  final Auth0 auth0 = Auth0(AppConfig.DOMAIN, AppConfig.CLIENTID);

  bool get isWebViewLoading => _isWebViewLoading;

  void loadWebView({String? url}) {
    final dashboardUrl = Uri.parse(AppConfig.login).replace(queryParameters: {
      'access_token': PrefUtils.getString(ACCESS_TOKEN),
      'token_type': PrefUtils.getString(TOKEN_TYPE),
      'refresh_token': PrefUtils.getString(REFRESH_TOKEN),
      'expires_in': PrefUtils.getString(EXPIRES_AT),
      'id_token': PrefUtils.getString(ID_TOKEN),
      'scope': PrefUtils.getString(SCOPES)
    }).toString();

    flutterWebviewPlugin.launch(
      dashboardUrl,
      appCacheEnabled: true,
      userAgent:
          'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Mobile Safari/537.36',
    );

    flutterWebviewPlugin.onStateChanged
        .listen((WebViewStateChanged state) async {
      if (state.type == WebViewState.startLoad) {
        _isWebViewLoading = true;
        notifyListeners();
      } else if (state.type == WebViewState.finishLoad) {
        _isWebViewLoading = false;
        notifyListeners();
      }
    });
// Additional listeners can be added as needed, such as for URL changes
    flutterWebviewPlugin.onUrlChanged.listen((String url) {
      if (url.contains(AppConfig.LOGOUT_URL)) {
        // Implement logout logic
        // Redirect to login page, etc.
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    flutterWebviewPlugin.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

Could anyone suggest what I might be doing wrong or propose an alternative approach to achieve faster WebView loads on app restarts? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

RAM is used only for temporary usage. When the data is loaded in RAM we can call it cache, the purpose of this is to load data only when it is used, RAM is still occupied when the app is in a pause state. You can't store data in the RAM, when objects are not used space is cleared immediately by dart Garbage Collector. You can read more [here](https://nimafarzin-pr.medium.com/garbage-collection-in-dart-and-its-implications-in-flutter-aef9de51bfc4).

If you want to save data even when the app is killed, you can use [hive](https://pub.dev/packages/hive). This is fast and easy to use.

Comment: basically @Aizan, i think he wants to preserve the webview in such a way that if once the tabs are openned, then even the user terminates the app and comes back again, those tabs are renderred quickly and faster than the first time loading.

Comment: Maybe, but he says
"I am encountering difficulties preserving the cache of a WebView in Flutter, specifically when the app is terminated", terminated means the app is killed and no longer available in RAM